# Activate Maven Profile by Packaging

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-profiles

The [Release Notes of Maven 3.9.0](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.0/release-notes.html) state that you can now activate profiles by packaging.

Can someone give me an example how to do this?

Comment: according to [MNG-6609](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6609) and corresponding [PR](https://github.com/apache/maven/pull/849/files) now you may write something like `<activation><property><name>packaging</name><value>jar</value></property></activation>` in settings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can refer to [this introduction](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

See the section ***How can a profile be triggered? How does this vary according to the type of profile being used?***

Shortly it says the following:

> Since Maven 3.9.0 one can also evaluate the POM's packaging value by
> referencing property `packaging`. This is only useful where the profile
> activation is defined in a common parent POM which is reused among
> multiple Maven projects. The next example will trigger the profile
> when a project with packaging `war` is built:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>packaging</name>
        <value>war</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```