# Maven: deploy all artifacts except WAR

Tags: maven

I need to modify the deployment phase in order to avoid deploying WAR files to the repository of artifacts, when executing `mvn clean deploy` command.

By default, Maven builds all the artifacts and deploys all of them to the repository.

I tried to use the **maven-deploy-plugin**, to skip this phase, but it's not a good solution, because I use a parent pom file (used by a lot of internal applications of my company) and if I set it there, no artifacts are deployed.

Maybe if this plugin allows to filter by artifactID, it could help me to achieve the solution...

Comment: What is the background? Why do you want to avoid deploying the WARs?

Comment: Because the size of the wars is very large and they should never be uploaded to the repository. WARs are only intended to be deployed on web application servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is generally a good idea to deploy WARs to the repository. It is especially a good source if your web application server dies and you need to reload the WAR.

That said: Maven 3.9.0 introduced profile activation based on the packaging. You can put a profile for the packaging `war` into your parent POM. This profile then sets the `<property>` with name `maven.deploy.skip` to true.

Comment: In my opinion, you have the source code in a GIT TAG, and you can regenerate the WAR every time you want. The WAR size is very huge to be uploaded to a repository...
Please, could you give me more information about what you're saying of creating a profile in the parent POM? I like to investigate this way to see if it's valid for me :)
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75676171/927493

Comment: It's almost what I need, yes. But... does exist any way to deploy only the pom.xml and not the generated war?

Comment: @MarcGilSendra Why would you want to to do that? I would not say that that is impossible, but it would probably require to write your own Maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it. The solution I found combines the use of 2 plugins with the profile activation based on the packaging.

First configure the plugin `build-helper-maven-plugin` to set 2 properties by regex: the repository ID and the repository URL, used later to deploy the individual pom file of the WAR module. This is used to deploy the module to the snapshots or release repository.

Then configure the plugin `maven-deploy-plugin` to skip the default execution, and configure a new execution to `deploy-file`. In this configuration, you set the pom file to use, and the file to upload (the same pom file). Also you set the repository ID and the repository URL set in the previous step. Alternatively you can set to deploy the sources file too.

```
<profile>
<!-- Actived only for war projects. Avoid to upload the war file.
Only pom.xml and sources file will be deployed -->
<activation>
    <property>
        <name>packaging</name>
        <value>war</value>
    </property>
</activation>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Create two variables repoId and repoURL -->
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <id>repository-snapshot-or-release</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>regex-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <regexPropertySettings>
                                <regexPropertySetting>
                                    <name>repoId</name>
                                    <value>
                                        ${project.version}${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.id}${project.distributionManagement.repository.id}</value>
                                    <regex>
                                        (?=.*SNAPSHOT).*(${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.id}).*|.*(${project.distributionManagement.repository.id}).*</regex>
                                    <replacement>$1$2</replacement>
                                    <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                                </regexPropertySetting>
                                <regexPropertySetting>
                                    <name>repoUrl</name>
                                    <value>
                                        ${project.version}${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</value>
                                    <regex>
                                        (?=.*SNAPSHOT).*(${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}).*|.*(${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}).*</regex>
                                    <replacement>$1$2</replacement>
                                    <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                                </regexPropertySetting>
                            </regexPropertySettings>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
                            <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                            <file>./pom.xml</file>
                            <packaging>pom</packaging>
                            <sources>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-sources.jar</sources>
                            <repositoryId>${repoId}</repositoryId>
                            <url>${repoUrl}</url>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Why do you want to have the POM if you don't have the WAR? What is it good for?

Comment: I think I answered you previously... The war can be generated from the GIT TAG. I think it's not a good idea to upload 150MB or 200MB of a war to the Nexus repository. But we want to have this artifact registered in Nexus.